# Save a variables in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How can I save and load variables constantly ? I find the Shared-Preferences but dont understand it well. For example I got a variable  which is called

> int global_coins

How can  I load or save it ? Thank You !

Comment: What don't you understand using SharedPreferences? This is well explained here (and the others options available to save app datas): http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: If you don't understand any particular thing about SharedPreferences, then it's better to ask about it. You question is too vague and there's no way to answer it.

Comment: Maybe someone can give a example ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Comment: @user3202845 There is an example in the link I posted. And i'm sure you can find plenty using your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do something like this to store a variable:

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.shared_preferences_file), 0);
Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt(context.getString(parameterRid), value);
editor.commit();
```

And something like this to read a variable:

```
SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getString(R.string.shared_preferences_file), 0);
return sp.getInt(context.getString(parameterRid), defaultValue);
```

You should really read the documentation for [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), it's really simple to understand and [the official guide to data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) is very useful.